# How do I extract DNS IPs using a script?

Tags: scripts, dns

I want to extract the ip addresses and the hostnames from the dns server list (100 ips) and put it in a file. What would be the best command to use?
I tried using `cut` but due to varying lengths of hostnames, the ips and hostnames do not come out together.

Comment: You should show at least a chunk of your input file, and probably you should consider using `awk`.

Comment: What is the current command you're using?

Comment: I tried with sed on a file, like this  `sed '/^;/d' filename | xarg sed '/^$/d/'> out` to seperate the hostname and ip addreess and leave out IN / A/ PTR /CNAME. but i am not sure this is the right way. I must tell you, i am a starter with scripts.

Comment: Yes, we would need to understand the data structure around the dns server list your referencing. For example; our the fields separated by commas, spaces, tabs, etc...Once you know that you can parse with awk accordingly.

Comment: ok. Here is an extract from the file............ online          IN      A       192.168.5.5
users1          IN      A       192.168.5.1
users2          IN      A       192.168.5.2
users3          IN CNAME      online
user4.el.com. IN A 192.168.2.3
online5.demo.el.com. IN A 192.168.7.3
Now, i need to IN/A/CNAME from the list. See the last one which is a subdomain, its causing real headaches for me . i need the full host address and the ip address as well

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution here?

Comment: Can we close this question please? Not looking for a solution anymore.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect output to a text file, add this to end of commmand you are using to view dns:

```
      > textfile.txt
```

will output to textfile.txt